# HTML large image performance problems

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I'm trying to make a sick slider like this http://learnlakenona.com/

But I'm having major performance problems in chrome (it seems their site doesn't even run the slider on chrome). I'm displaying the images by using background-image CSS on divs, adding them as img tags caused even more lag.

I disabled all javascript and noticed I was still getting lag just with having some huge images sitting on top of eachother.

Here's just some images sitting there. Try changing the size of the panels, redrawing the images locks it up. (sometimes it runs okay for a bit, it's weird)
http://jsfiddle.net/LRynj/2/

Does anyone have an idea how I can get acceptable performance on a slider like this!? (images need to be pretty big)

Comment: I noticed that two of the images are 1.15MB and 3.76MB. Try converting those to GIFs to decrease file size to a few hundred KB. Won't look as good but something you can try...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site uses HUGE transparent PNGs for a parallax effect, so:

- you'll have to reduce the total weight of your images: you can try to convert these PNGs to PNG-8 if they aren't already. Quantizations algorithms and such do a very good job at reducing images to 256 colors without too much degradation of quality.
- you've to keep transparency for the parallax effect. Both types of transparency are compatible with PNG-8: GIF-like opaque/tranparent bit of transparency on each pixel and "PNG-32"-like (PNG-24 + 8 bits of transparency) where each pixel has 256 levels of transparency. Adobe Fireworks is particularly good at creating such "PNG-8+alpha" images; converters also exist but they're not perfect (depends of your images).
- loading the minimum part of your image that is seen immediately and only later the rest of your 9600px-wide (!) would greatly reduce the time to first view. You can achieve that by slicing your images by chunks of 1920 or 2560px, load the viewed part of the 3 images as background images and via a script that would execute only after the DOM is [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) load all the other parts. Not too much parts because that would imply more assets to download but still not a 4MB sprite :) Bonus: by slicing your 3 images to PNG-8, each PNG will have its own 256-colors palette and overall quality will be better (not as perfect as a PNG-24 but better than a single 9600px PNG-8 that could only use 256 colors total. More shades of grey for the man suit in one PNG, more shiny colors for the ball-and-stick molecule, etc

EDIT: and don't ever try to load that on a smartphone! I do like Media Queries and avoid UA detection because it isn't needed most of the time and never perfect but that's one of the cases (choosing to load 8MB of images) where it'll be welcome... Ignoring users that don't have optic fiber and won't wait for your site to display is another issue not related to your question.

Answer (score 4):

Optimize your image assets by resizing them in an image editor or lowering the quality.

You can also use free tools online:

http://sixrevisions.com/tools/8-excellent-tools-for-optimizing-your-images/

Comment: Images are too large to be processed by the online tools, haha. Yeah that might be the problem. I'll get em' optimized and see if it works, thanks.